# Form data is not correct with Suave web server

Tags: f#, suave

I am trying to receive a confirmation from AWS' SNS system.
It sends a message through a POST to a webserver and I'm receiving it using Suave.

When I get the message, the *form* field is truncated, I am receiving:

```
"{\n  \"Type\" : \"SubscriptionConfirmation\",\n  \"MessageId\" : \"13dd68fa-2720-419a-8d8a-edc9f4466ea3\",\n  \"Token\" : \"2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e2425e90ccf23f36200405c1942ea85f0874b382c47327c4bfd63203eace5240bb7b253428af362a04a61c8f98ab1718c679e9e27594529615adf5d86729374cce472768b91622851aced957c1dcddf21e3d82b48f5ff528c8dbc911179a3f26126a8d7f00\",\n  \"TopicArn\" : \"arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:960544703730:igorbot\",\n  \"Message\" : \"You have chosen to subscribe to the topic arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:960544703730:igorbot.\\nTo confirm the subscription, visit the SubscribeURL included in this message.\",\n  \"SubscribeURL\" : \"https://sns.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/?Action",
    "ConfirmSubscription"
```

so it's an unfinished json...

but when I look at the *rawForm* field, I get the whole message:

```
{
  "Type" : "SubscriptionConfirmation",
  "MessageId" : "0645c009-f4fa-4fb7-9c94-127e98f5eb76",
  "Token" : "2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e2425e90ccf23f36200406641a9f63b753dad1d31c61da2ebeea8cdaeed2e3c04f701bd08e2d2c9cac65676979e43c1089a96779f9b57a0e0f072013333db51472ca43c1e6a0854cf3af6769d95c7911d74c9e2bec22db93de90e537d480070891ddaaa548",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:960544703730:igorbot",
  "Message" : "You have chosen to subscribe to the topic arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:960544703730:igorbot.\nTo confirm the subscription, visit the SubscribeURL included in this message.",
  "SubscribeURL" : "https://sns.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:960544703730:igorbot&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e2425e90ccf23f36200406641a9f63b753dad1d31c61da2ebeea8cdaeed2e3c04f701bd08e2d2c9cac65676979e43c1089a96779f9b57a0e0f072013333db51472ca43c1e6a0854cf3af6769d95c7911d74c9e2bec22db93de90e537d480070891ddaaa548",
  "Timestamp" : "2021-03-13T20:36:21.918Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "FBnpuGtkZmzox+5ryo1/4k1hgwmoeuvcptQ2dOyyneShVHovmdemMqo9JFTzbBFelTN7FMojX/sIjFs2dZoQYeqEgsQW9WqCiEstDQu0toHn7KKxapzIoGfjfh6Rikfy8Liv88RRNLC2DLtxWW2JWr5Mmwkjtro/pm7vyJhfp5G4qcAB3gtBOtVm+XOAai6rY7obcMojkmMr4jDd9UqutV6imyYDCH+PvUCnc7aKg6p4EmZO33VlRibIPa5PiN1Sj/mmNhyoeR4pGu+0Jci+utvonXaYPgtlDuEyoVcgUQ6lki1xiclIRpDm4FvOL5tvUSq+Jdjz3prlNDNM8AuQpQ==",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-010a507c1833636cd94bdb98bd93083a.pem"
}
```

At first I thought the output was truncated, but then I narrowed it down. Posting this line:

```
{
  "SubscribeURL" : "https://sns.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:960544703730:igorbot&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e2425e90ccf23f36200406641a9f63b753dad1d31c61da2ebeea8cdaeed2e3c04f701bd08e2d2c9cac65676979e43c1089a96779f9b57a0e0f072013333db51472ca43c1e6a0854cf3af6769d95c7911d74c9e2bec22db93de90e537d480070891ddaaa548"
}
```

will fail and get truncated at the first '=' sign. Then:

```
{
  "SubscribeURL" : "abc=3"
}
```

will cause Suave to fail. When sent as form data, it will not be converted to a string properly.

Is there any setting related to encoding, etc that would allow to prevent this? (since I can't ask AWS to escape all their '=' signs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON and form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, to be specific) have different syntax. Form data looks like `key1=value1&key2=value2`, so Suave is breaking the string on `&` and `=` in order to parse it.

You can parse JSON using `mapJson` instead. Something like this should work:

```
open System.Runtime.Serialization
open Suave
open Suave.Json

[<DataContract>]
type Subscription =
    {
        [<field: DataMember(Name = "SubscribeURL")>]
        SubscribeUrl : string;
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let app = mapJson (fun sub -> sprintf "URL: %s" sub.SubscribeUrl)
    startWebServer defaultConfig app
    0
```

Comment: how would that work when I can get different types of objects on the same route? AWS is sending subscription messages as well as payload messages, from SNS, which can be anything, not necessarily JSON. Just that one message has JSON in it.

Comment: I don’t know anything about SNS, but I assume there must be something in the request that indicates what type of data is being sent, yes? I suppose you’ll have to read that value first and then interpret the rest of the request accordingly. It does sound tricky, though.

Comment: SNS is a queue system. When you register, they send that JSON and you know it exists because of a header value; after that, it's all client messages which can be anything. Because of that I need to check the header to see if I should expect that JSON and then decode the form field. But I don't understand why it truncates the output at the '=' sign.

Comment: Form data looks like `key1=value1&key2=value2`, so Suave is breaking the string on `&` and `=` in order to parse it. I would look at the `Content-Type` header as a guide to interpreting the request correctly.

Comment: ok, that explains the issue then! In the meantime, I found that I could just transform the rawForm into a string and parse it without problem. That's probably the best way going forward since I didn't expect Suave to try to interpret the data

Comment: For anyone browsing this in the future, I updated my answer to directly address your actual question about form data syntax.